# Constant time algorithm for k'th number with n 1's in its binary expansion

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, optimization

I'm looking for an algorithm that can efficiently find the k'th number with exactly n 1's in its binary expansion, in constant time. (Ordering the numbers in ascending order).

For example if k = 3 and n = 2:
The numbers with 2 1's in their binary expansion are:
[0b11, 0b101, 0b110, 0b1001, ...]
Hence the answer is 0b110 = 6.

So far I have only thought of the brute force method, creating every possible permutation of 1's and 0's (with exactly n 1's) within some range, sorting the results and extracting the k'th value.

I am not entirely sure a constant time solution exists but I am sure there is something better than what I have.

Comment: Create a function to count how many strings of a set length have a set number of 1s, then do digit by digit DP or binary search.

Comment: Since the expected binary length is obviously Ω(log k), there is no constant time algorithm, at least programmatically. O(log k) algorithms (such as the one answered by @frank-yellin ) are the optimal solution. Do you also need a working implementation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write the code for you.  But here's the general idea.

You can ask:  How many `n`-digit numbers are there with exactly `n` 1s.  [Hint, exactly 1.]. How many `n+1`-digit numbers are there with exactly `n` 1s.  [`n-1`, since the 0 can go anywhere except the first digit.  You can continue and see that there are `choose(q-1, k-1)` `q`-digit numbers with precisely `k` ones.

So you figure out

1. how big `q`, the length of the answer is,
2. how many numbers of length less that length `q` have precisely `k` 1s.  Call that `p`.
3. So you need to find the `n-p`th `q`-digit number with exactly `k` 1s.

You know the first digit of your answer is a `1`.  Is the second digit a zero or a one?  Count how many have a zero in that position vs a 1.  Continue until you've calculated the entire value.

The details are a little bit tricky, and you need to make sure your counting is precise.  But you can get the answer is log(n).

Comment: You can go digit by digit, or if you have a function that counts how many have n ones below k, then binary search.

Comment: @qwr.  How are you going to write that function?

Comment: you need a helper function that counts how many d length integers have k ones. you end up still having to go digit by digit, doing suffix strings below your input.

Comment: it's funny that I was working on a project euler problem with this method yesterday